# Saving and loading Number from plist file

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I'm trying to save and load the current level from a plist in my game.

This is what my plist looks like:

[image]

This is my code to load and save data right now:

```
class SavedLevel: NSObject, NSCoding {
 var level: Double

 required init(level:Double = 1) {
    self.level = level
 }

 required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    self.level = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "Level") as? Double ?? 0
 }

 func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encode(level, forKey: "Level")
 }
}
class DataModel: NSObject {

 var saveLevels = SavedLevel()

 func documentsDirectory()->String {
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)
    let documentsDirectory = paths.first!
    return documentsDirectory
 }

 func dataFilePath()->String {
    return self.documentsDirectory().appendingFormat("/CurrentLevel.plist")
 }

 override init() {
    super.init()
    print("document file: \(documentsDirectory())")
    print("data file: \(dataFilePath())")
 }

 func saveData() {
        let data = NSMutableData()
        let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
        archiver.encode(saveLevels, forKey: "CurrentLevel")
        archiver.finishEncoding()
        data.write(toFile: dataFilePath(), atomically: true)
 }

 func loadData() {
        let path = self.dataFilePath()
        let defaultManager = FileManager()
        if defaultManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
            let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
            let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
            let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
            saveLevels = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "CurrentLevel") as! SavedLevel
            unarchiver.finishDecoding()
        }
 }
}
```

Here is how I increase the level count and how I try to save the current level of the player:

```
var currentLevelNum = 1

if score >= level.targetScore {
        gameOverPanel.image = UIImage(named: "LevelComplete")
        currentLevelNum = Int(dataModel.saveLevels.level)
        if currentLevelNum < NumLevels {
            currentLevelNum += 1
            dataModel.saveLevels.level = Double(currentLevelNum)
        }
        dataModel.saveData()
        print("Updated level: ",dataModel.saveLevels.level)
        showGameOver()
    } else if movesLeft == 0 {
        gameOverPanel.image = UIImage(named: "GameOver")
        dataModel.saveData()
        showGameOver()
    }
```

Here is how I try to save the data in the AppDelegate file (with the unnecessary code omitted) :

```
class AppDelegate {

   var dataModel = DataModel()

   func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
       saveData()
       print("Level when app was sent to background: ",dataModel.saveLevels.level)
   }

   func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
       saveData()
       print("Level when app was terminated: ",dataModel.saveLevels.level)

   }

   func saveData() {
       dataModel.saveData()
   }
```

The level variable in SavedLevel is being updated when a level is completed and is increased by 1. But when I send the app to the background the original value of Level in the plist is printed.

Example:

```
Level at startup:  0.0
Updated level:  1.0
Updated level:  2.0
Level when app was sent to background:  1.0
Updated level:  3.0
Level when app was sent to background:  1.0
```

Something to do with saving the level isn't working right and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: FYI - `UserDefaults` is a much simpler place to keep track of something as simple as a number.

Comment: You should use Background execution. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
    let level = myDict?.object(forKey: "level") as! String
    print("Your level is: \(level)")
}
```